# ¿Por qué al crear una función retorna undefined al ser definida?

Tags: javascript, funciones, consola

¿Porque luego de definir una función a ***través de la consola del navegador*** se retorna "*undefined*"? ¿Porque ocurre? ¿Que faltaría en la declaración de una función para que esto No ocurriera?

Por ejemplo al crear una función con la siguiente sintaxis se retorna "*undefined*":

```
function miFuncion(algo){
    return algo;
}
//salida: undefined
```

También si uso una sintaxis como la siguiente se retorna "*undefined*":

```
var miFuncion = function(algo){
    return algo;
}
//Salida: undefined
```

pero, cuando se prueba algo como:

```
miFuncion = function(algo){
    return algo;
}
```

cambia el retorno luego de crearse la función, ***¿Algo cambia usando esta sintaxis?***

Agrego una captura de pantalla para que sea mas objetiva la idea que plantea la pregunta

[image]

Comment: Para que podamos ser mas claros en la respuesta, seria genial que nos pudieras pasar un codigo de ejemplo donde estas utilizando tu funcion. Como te dijo @Aprendiz es probable que al no pasarle un valor en algo, te devuelva undefined. Espero nos puedas dar un ejemplo asi podemos ser mas claros con la respuesta!

Comment: @matnalopez gracias por comentar, bueno, hablaba de especificamente de cuando creo una funcion a travez de la consola de un navegador como Chrome o firefox

Comment: pregunta, ¿entiendes la diferencia de definir una funcion e invocar una funcion definida? esta función recibe un parámetro `algo`, si ejecutas la funcion sin enviarle parámetros este dirá que algo no está definido. En tus ejemplos solo muestras las definiciones de las funciones pero no como las estás invocando, si agregas el como las invocas tendremos claro que error estas cometiendo.

Comment: @LPZadkiel si, entiendo la diferencia, y pues reitero, es al definir la funcion, agregre un captura para que sea un explicita la idea de mi pregunta, gracias

Comment: cuando dices "al definir la funcion" eso significa que estas en la consola de chrome haciendo pruebas?

Comment: Si, si, literalmente creo una funcion en la consola y me devuelve undefined

Comment: no sabría decirte exactamente el porque, pero creo que tiene que ver con lo permisivo que es javascript, cuando pones por delante `var` estas declarando una variable entonces la sentencia que creaste no tiene nada que retornar por lo que devuelve `undefined` y es que las declaraciones no tienen un valor, sin embargo cuando defines una variable sin tener `var` por delante javascript asume que la variable existe y te retorna el contenido de la variable.

Comment: ojo que esto es especulación mía no lo he comprobado, además el hecho de que cada sentencia retorne algo esto no es propio de javascript es cosa de chrome al ya estar en la consola asume que quieres imprimir el resultado de tu código por lo que te retorna algo cada vez que ingresas código en ella (consola de chrome)

Comment: @LPZadkiel entiendo, suena bastante coherente tu especulacion, seguire buscando informacion a ver si encuentro algo "oficial", muchas gracias

Comment: el "undefined" es propio del navegador o consola de nodejs, imagina que cuando  utlizas estas herramientas estas modo debugger y la idea es identificar el error si tu escribe en la consola de tu navegador un numero /string e incluso una variable este te lo imprime sin hacer explicitamente el console.log,con esto quiero decir el navegador con lo que intentes escribir tratara de retornar el resultado, caso contrario para la asignacion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La **consola** del navegador está diseñada para tomar la última expresión, buscar su valor de retorno y luego mostrar dicho valor.

Cuando realizas una declaración de asignación **JavaScript** asigna el valor asignado, pero la **consola** realizará un paso más y es el de devolver el valor de retorno de la última declaración.

En la **consola** declarar una variable usando o no usando la palabra clave `var` realmente hace lo mismo: asignar la propiedad al objeto `window`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La diferencia es que la declaración `var` no posee un valor de retorno es por esto que la **consola** devuelve `undefined` mientras que al usar la declaración sin la palabra clave `var` la **consola** inmediatamente retorna el valor asignado.

Cabe anotar que al declarar funciones (sin importar la forma en que se haga) también se retorna `undefined` ya que la declaración de funciones tampoco posee un valor de retorno.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero haber sido claro con la explicación.

Answer (score 3):

La función esta creada, pero el argumento `algo` no tiene valor alguno asignado por eso retorna `undefined`.

Prueba lo siguiente:

Para tu primer función quedando así:

```
function miFuncion(algo = 10){
    return algo;
}

console.log(miFuncion())
```

Le asignamos un valor por defecto al parámetro y posteriormente imprimimos en pantalla.

Dando como resultado:

```
//10
```

Por ejemplo, puedes comprobar el tipo que tiene dicho parámetro de este modo:

```
function miFuncion(algo){
    return typeof(algo);
}

console.log(miFuncion())
```

Lo cual retorna:

```
//undefined
```

Caso contrario si le asignas un valor como al inicio te explico y repites el código haciendo uso de `typeof()` te devolverá:

```
//number
```

Lo anterior debería ser aplicable para los 3 casos que muestras.

Comment: Gracias, pero realmente no surge ningún cambio, en el primer caso devuelve *10* (por el console.log), pero luego devuelve *undefined* de nuevo, igual pasa con el caso del *typeof()*